# Swift Combine - Multiple Observable (CurrentValueSubject or PassthroughSubject) into one but wait for update from all

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

Ok, so I am using the last version of Swift with Combine.
My goal is to combine 3 `CurrentValueSubject` or `PassthroughSubject` into one Sequence by waiting for all of them to emit once.

Let's take the following example:

```
var var1 = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>)([])
var var2 = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(0)
var var3 = CurrentValueSubject<Date?, Never>(nil)
```

I want to have all value in one when they each emit a new sequence.

So I could do something like that:

```
Publishers
    .CombineLatest3(var1, var2, var3)
    .sink(receivedValue: { var1, var2, var3 in
        print("Printed!")
    })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Alright, so that kind of works, but it will print `Printed!` 3 times on the second pass.
Let's say, if I do the following code, it will do it only once.

```
var1.send(["test","test1"])
var2.send(0)
var3.send(Date())
```

but I add this

```
var1.send(["test","test1"])
var2.send(0)
var3.send(Date())
var1.send(["test","test1"])
```

It will trigger again my Combined Publishers. And I want to trigger it again only if I have the following scenario:

```
var1.send(["test","test1"])
var2.send(0)
var3.send(Date())
var1.send(["test2","test3"])
var2.send(2)
var3.send(Date())
```

I hope this makes sense, let me know if you have an idea of how to tackle this issue!

Comment: You can use `Publishers.Zip3` - it will only emit a value once all three have emitted their values

Comment: Damn @NewDev thank you so much! I read in the doc about Zip, but I didn't understand it was doing this in particular! 

Comment: Combine is based on the Reactive Extensions (Rx) paradigm. This means you can take advantage of almost a decade's worth of Rx tutorials and guides to better understand what Combine offers. For example, rxmarbles lets you visually, interactively explore both [combineLatest](https://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) and [zip](https://rxmarbles.com/#zip).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Zip3`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/zip3) seems to be what you are looking for:

```
Publishers
    .Zip3(var1, var2, var3)
    .sink(receivedValue: { var1, var2, var3 in
        print("Printed!")
    })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

From the docs of [`zip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/zip/zip(_:_:)-284xh):

> Use `zip(_:_:)` to return a new publisher that combines the elements from two additional publishers to publish a tuple to the downstream. The returned publisher waits until all three publishers have emitted an event, then delivers the oldest unconsumed event from each publisher as a tuple to the subscriber.

See [a visualisation on RxMarbles](https://rxmarbles.com/#zip)!